# How to: securely store secret tokens when publishing iOS App (Nativescript)

Tags: ios, nativescript

My Nativescript app has some secret api tokens. I want to publish the app to the iOS app store. What do I need to do to keep the tokens secret when I publish the app?

I see a discussion [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/best-practice-for-secrets-like-using-environmental-variables/6997/22) about storing secrets using webpack environmental variables. I am new to webpack, but it seems like this is the best way to do it.

Following that discussion, I am able put my tokens into the webpack bundle (instead of hardcoding it), like this:

```
$ tns run ios --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot --env.secret_token="yaySecret"
```

But does this keep "yaySecret" secret? I don't see this addressed anywhere in NS docs or online.

I assume this bundle command creates a bundle, and then this bundle becomes part of what Apple publishes. But then isn't Apple able to view "yaySecret"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uglify actually does the job here (`--env.uglify`).

`--env.secret_token` will be just a parameter that is passed to the compiler. It will replace the occurrence of the variable in source code with actual value based on your webpack define configuration.

You should have something similar to this in your webpack config

```
 // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
  "global.SECRET_TOKEN": JSON.stringify(env.secret_token),
  "process": undefined,
 }),
```

So all occurrence of `global.SECRET_TOKEN` in your actual source code will be replaced by actual token you passed in command line.

So far it had nothing to do with security, reverse engineering the APK may show the entire source code and token value. Using minimizers like **Uglify** is what makes your code hard to read.

There are many other minimizers / obfuscators in market, [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) is one free tool I have seen people using with NativeScript often. All of these tools have tons of options, if you want to encrypt your code properly, you might need to pay more attention to those options.

There are even paid tools like [jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com/). Using Obfuscators are not limited to NativeScript / JavaScript, even many native android apps use Java Obfuscator to prevent extraction of source code & sensitive information from the APK. So using an Obfuscator is very much common irrespective of platform you choose.

Additionally what you could do is, do not simply hard code your token. You may pass some encrypted value to `env.secret_token`, then write some complex function which can take this encrypted value and give you the actual token at run time. End of the day it's all about making your code harder to break.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough reply. I am surprised there is not more out there about this critical issue. So is it fair to say that, in your view, the main way to secure a token is in fact to use webpack + uglify, with additional options possible like you mentioned to add extra layers?

Comment: Following up after awhile, as I look again at hiding a value passed in a webpack bundle ($ tns bundle ios --env.uglify --env.hideMe="howToHideMe?" ). Still looking for good solutions. Uglify is limited, jscrambler is too pricey, and javascript-obfuscator is not kept up. You mention writing a complex function. How would that work? The function would itself be in the code base, no? In that case, a hacker could just see it and run it. So how could a complex function act to hide the secret? Any other possibilities?

Comment: I don't think so. It's either you spend your time in writing a smart obfuscation for saving your secret Or pay the price to get it done, may be jscrambler when you are not happy with uglify or javascript-obfuscator.

Comment: Huh. Seems unfortunate that there is not a way for people to publish their nativescript apps securely unless they (i) want to pay $1000+/year or (ii) use a library (javascript-obfuscator) that the creator says he is no longer maintaining. Are there maybe angular methods we can take advantage of?